# How to efficiently check for variables in a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have eight variables that i want to check agianst the current line in the for loop. I think there might be a better way to do this than what i currently have.

I now have 5 different if statements

```
with open('stuff.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line == str(sameDay):
            bag.append(line)
        if line == str(threeDaysAgo):
            bag.append(line)
        if line == str(weekAgo):
            bag.append(line)
        if line == str(monthAgo):
            bag.append(line)
        if line == str(threeDaysAgo):
            bag.append(line)
```

Comment: In all cases, you append `line`. What's the use of separate checks then? You can have one `if` check to check if `line` equals any of the days/weeks/months and append.

Comment: your variables, (someDay,...) are string type ?

Comment: @rusu_ro1 they are 'datetime.date', but awakenedhakis solution works

Comment: I think almost all other answers will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better than having many `if` statements, and also more efficient that calling on `append` multiple times.

```
variables = set(map(str, [sameDay, threeDayAgo, weekAgo...]))

def check_variables(lines):
    for line in lines:
        if line in variables:
            yield line
```

Edit: Made variables into a `set` since it runs `in` faster than a `list`. Useful if `lines` is really long.

Comment: `yield` is more memory efficient than creating a `list` and then outputting. This is due to the lazy evaluation that comes built in with `yield` and generators. Also, if you do want to make a list, and not a generator, calling `list(check_variables(...))` is actually faster than calling `append` internally.

Answer (score 0):

```
if line in [str(x) for x in [sameDay, threeDaysAgo, weekAgo, monthAgo]]:
    bag.append(line)
```

You might want to save the list in a variable beforehand to make this a bit more clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove define a list of `VALID_LINES` and check if the read line is in the list. If YES, then append to the bag.
Moreover, we can use list comprehension for efficiency.

```
VALID_LINES = [str(sameDay), str(threeDaysAgo), str(weekAgo), str(monthAgo), str(threeDaysAgo)]
with open('stuff.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    [bag.append(line) for line in lines if line in VALID_LINES]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
acceptable = {str(e) for e in [sameDay, threeDaysAgo, monthAgo, hreeDaysAgo]}
with open('stuff.txt', 'r') as f:
    bag = [line for line in f.readlines() if line in acceptable ]
```

Answer (score 0):

As python does not have switch-case statements, so you can use the following function as switch case. And you can implement your function return logic as per your requirement. As you are appending line every time so this function returns the same line every time.

```py
def f(line): 
    return { 
        'sameDay': line, 
        'threeDaysAgo': line, 
        'weekAgo':line, 
        'monthAgo':line, 
        'threeDaysAgo':line 
        }.get(line)

bag = []

for line in lines:
    bag.append(f(line))
```

Comment: gives `KeyError` if line does not match.

Comment: Instead, use ```get``` method on a dictionary, which will not raise an exception.